# Why operator = is overloaded by default in VB?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6

Most of the programming languages e.g. C/C++/C#/Java/Python use `=` for assignment and `==` for equality test. Some programming languages like Pascal use `=` for equality test and `:=` for assignment. But in VB, operator `=` is overloaded by default, which can be used for both assignment and equality test. (Like operator `<<` and `>>` in C++, which can be used for both bitwise shift and stream I/O). As a result, All versions of VB (including VB.NET) cannot implement chain assignment in most programming languages (expression like `a = b = 1` is chain assignment in C/C++/C#/Java/Python. But in VB, it is equivalent to `a = b == 1` in C/C++/C#/Java/Python). Why all version of VB including VB.NET overload operator `=` by default, not using a new operator for equality test?

Comment: If it's an initial assignment, you can have `Dim a As Integer = 2, b = a, c = a, d = 3`. Otherwise, if you need to *synchronize* different variable, you probably don't need variables but properties of classes. Then you can handle the *internals* as you please (you know, OOP)

Comment: Because that's how it is in BASIC?

Comment: > But in VB, operator = is overloaded by default. It's not overloaded, but rather a simplified/shortcut version of the actual assigment syntax in (traditional) BASIC, which is `Let a = 1`. Perfectly valid in VBA, btw. And similar to e.g. the `s += "abc"` string concatination being a short version of `s = s + "abc"`. Different languages, different rules.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's true as far as it goes, but I think it's also fair to ask why that's how it is in BASIC.  It's true that the C family aren't a great example since they are more or less unique in treating assignment as an operation (which essentially requires separate tokens for assignment and equality), but it's also the case that Fortran (`.EQ.` for equality) and Pascal (`:=` for assignment) treat assignment as a statement but still have separate tokens for assignment and testing equality.

Comment: @Jimi The syntax of the statement you showed is *not* valid VB6 code, for a couple of reasons.  Firstly, VB6 doesn't support initialization in the declaration at all (I wish it did).  Furthermore, the statement as shown, assuming the initializations were removed, would end up with a as an integer, and all the rest variants.

Comment: @MarkMoulding That's clearly VB.NET

Comment: > but I think it's also fair to ask why that's how it is in BASIC. You should rather ask why it's _not_ that way in other languages, considering that in mathematics where this all stems from "=" is used _both_ as a comparison  operator _and_ an assigment.

Comment: @HelO'Ween At least as far as Fortran goes, maybe they used `.EQ.` for consistency with `.AND.` and `.OR.` as well as `.GT.` and `.LT.`?  I believe in newer versions they also adopted `==` which is presumably based on the same usage in the C family of languages.  I'm not familiar with Pascal.  The greater-than/less-than I think might have been due to operating with a reduced character set originally.

Comment: In VB.NET, parameters can be passed by name, which uses `:=`: [Passing Arguments by Position and by Name (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-position-and-by-name). You might see that as a different sort of `=`.

Comment: The answer to the question is a philosophical debate about semantics.  You can learn more about it here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Assignment_versus_equality  Largely, the behavior is "unexpected" for someone familiar with other languages, but VB6 does allow things like `A = B = C`, where A is assigned a boolean result from comparing B and C.  The first `=` is assignment, the second is equality.  VB.NET simply follows VB6's syntax, which likely more or less follows BASIC syntax, which dates back to 1963.  Age, history, and precedence answer your question.